# Polymer paper-input after tap size expands with chrome on mobile

Tags: polymer

I am using polymer for developing an app on mobile. Everything works great except  one problem. In Chrome V40.0.2214.109 on Android 5.0.1 paper-input expands size after tap.

```
 <paper-input-decorator label="Ort eingeben und auf Auto klicken!" flex floatingLabel >
        <input id="inputAdresse" is="core-input">
 </paper-input-decorator>
```

It looks good on an mobile app created with PhoneGap. 
When I access the app from the web there is a problem after clicking in the input field using Chrome browser on mobile. The whole window is enlarged so that icons disappear on the right side.
With firefox on mobile it works fine.

Is this a known bug?

Sorry, I tried to attach images, but I need at least 10 reputations to post screen shots.

Comment: are you setting the viewport size? <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no"> kind of sounds like the page is changing the scale when focusing the input.

Comment: my setting is <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">

Comment: i would guess that changing that to user-scalable=no would fix that.

Comment: But why it works in firefox and in the PhoneGap app? I will try 'scalable=no' and will report back.

Comment: the user scale is only for mobile phone browsers.

Comment: Ok, thank you! set user-scalable=no has solved the problem.